# jQuery Set wait time before a function executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, time-wait

How can i set wait time for this function.

```
function UpdateMedicaitonHistory(data) {
     MedicaitonHistoryGrid();
//set a wait time to finish MedicaitonHistoryGrid() like for 3 seconds
// then execute the below code.
if ($("#MedHistoryGridSec").is(":visible")) {
            alert("yes we have grid");
      }
else{
     alert("No Grid");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you rather add a callback to `MedicationHistoryGrid()` that would execute when it has finished, instead of trying to guess when it's ready?

Comment: well it has a chain and dependencies which is not allowing me to do that way. That's why to keep it simple i choose this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
     if($('#MedHistoryGridSec').is(':visible'))
         alert('yes');
     else
         alert('no');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap up the code in a callback function and run it after three seconds using [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
var afterThreeSeconds = function() {
  if ($("#MedHistoryGridSec").is(":visible")) {
    alert("yes we have grid");
  }
  else{
    alert("No Grid");
  }
}

window.setTimeout(afterThreeSeconds, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a parameter to the medication history grid function taking a function containing the code you want executed after that function succeeds which you can then call at the end of the medication history grid function?